# Starting bootstrap 3 project?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Does anybody knows what is best pratice to start a bootstrap project?

Shall elements start with

**col-md.***

or

**col-sm.***

Example what is common pratice?

```
<div class="col-md-12">
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what device your almost users use.

- If your user almost use smartphones, you should apply `.col-xs-*`
- If your user almost use tablets , you should apply `.col-sm-*`
- If your user almost use laptops , you should apply `.col-md-*`
- If your user almost use laptops/desktops, you should apply `.col-lg-*`

If you don't know what device your users use and you know the screen resolution, you can reference the table:

- Small grid (≥768px) = `.col-sm-*`
- Medium grid (≥992px) = `.col-md-*`
- Large grid (≥1200px) = `.col-lg-*`

Answer (score 0):

Starting a Bootstrap project is best supported using the code from github or generating it using your IDE.

Your examples are both valid: the only difference is `col-md-12` defines a column grid with medium sized input and a dozen columns and `col-sm-12` does exactly the same twelve columns but in small size.